# How to Modify return type on Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma, prisma-graphql

```
prisma.academy_user_like_videos
  .findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: 2587,
    },
    orderBy: {
      created_ts: "desc",
    },
    select: {
      academy_videos: true,
    }
  })
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    academy_videos: {
      id: 279,
      user_id: 2428,
      publish_status_id: 2,
      approval_state_id: 1,
      title: 'Best Gear For Streaming!',
      description: 'Learn about all the essentials for streaming!',

    }  
}
]
```

**what i want**

```
 {
      id: 279,
      user_id: 2428,
      publish_status_id: 2,
      approval_state_id: 1,
      title: 'Best Gear For Streaming!',
      description: 'Learn about all the essentials for streaming!',
    }
```

Comment: You can use Prisma Client Extensions like this: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/result#add-custom-fields-or-methods-to-query-results to change the output format before sending the response

Comment: @NurulSundarani can you do for above please i am stuck from last 2 hours

Comment: Why can't you take the result that Prisma gives you and modify the structure to whatever you want and then return it at your API instead of trying to achieve this at the ORM level? While it's possible to modify it using prisma extensions, extensions are meant to add computed fields and other similar data that you don't want to store in the DB but still want to return, not really for use cases like this.

Comment: @JohnKim front end team does not like this

Comment: @Haseeb the API is your backend though... You can easily make this conversion at your REST API before you serve it.

Comment: @JohnKim thanks it was graphql issue is solved